# Pod not being scheduled even though resources available

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-statefulset

I am running a 4 worker node cluster in GCP.

And the current status of my nodes is :

**Node A**

```
Non-terminated Pods:         (4 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                              CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ---------                  ----                              ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  kube-system                calico-node-bfpbd                 250m (6%)     500m (12%)  100Mi (0%)       700Mi (5%)
  kube-system                kube-proxy-7br2g                  50m (1%)      100m (2%)   64Mi (0%)        256Mi (1%)
  kube-system                node-exporter-7kvcm               10m (0%)      20m (0%)    10Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)
  kube-system                tiller-deploy-56c4cf647b-5vsvb    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource  Requests    Limits
  --------  --------    ------
  cpu       310m (7%)   620m (15%)
  memory    174Mi (1%)  1006Mi (7%)
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:31:08 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:31:08 -0400   RouteCreated                 RouteController created a route
  OutOfDisk            False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:50 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:46 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure       False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:50 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:46 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:50 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:46 -0400   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:50 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:46 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:50 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:31:06 -0400   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
```

**Node B**

```
Non-terminated Pods:         (4 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                                  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ---------                  ----                                  ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  jenkins-test               jenkins-master    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                calico-node-qglbv                     250m (6%)     500m (12%)  100Mi (0%)       700Mi (5%)
  kube-system                kube-proxy-g74ff                      50m (1%)      100m (2%)   64Mi (0%)        256Mi (1%)
  kube-system                node-exporter-bvczb                   10m (0%)      20m (0%)    10Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource  Requests    Limits
  --------  --------    ------
  cpu       310m (7%)   620m (15%)
  memory    174Mi (1%)  1006Mi (7%)
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:31:06 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:31:06 -0400   RouteCreated                 RouteController created a route
  OutOfDisk            False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:49 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:46 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure       False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:49 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:46 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:49 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:46 -0400   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:49 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:46 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:49 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:31:06 -0400   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
```

**Node C**

```
Non-terminated Pods:         (3 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                   CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ---------                  ----                   ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  kube-system                calico-node-w9px6      250m (6%)     500m (12%)  100Mi (0%)       700Mi (5%)
  kube-system                kube-proxy-4r2ck       50m (1%)      100m (2%)   64Mi (0%)        256Mi (1%)
  kube-system                node-exporter-r92xs    10m (0%)      20m (0%)    10Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:31:01 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:31:01 -0400   RouteCreated                 RouteController created a route
  OutOfDisk            False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:42 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:49 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure       False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:42 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:49 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:42 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:49 -0400   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:42 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:49 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:42 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:31:09 -0400   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
```

**Node D**

```
Non-terminated Pods:         (9 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                                                               CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ---------                  ----                                                               ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  kube-system                addons-kubernetes-dashboard-8656b6fc5f-68wzm                       50m (1%)      200m (5%)   50Mi (0%)        256Mi (1%)
  kube-system                addons-nginx-ingress-controller-77579b6d64-sqzl7                   100m (2%)     300m (7%)   100Mi (0%)       512Mi (3%)
  kube-system                addons-nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-k8s-backend-5d6d4598ff-nfzt4    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                calico-node-h2t5b                                                  250m (6%)     500m (12%)  100Mi (0%)       700Mi (5%)
  kube-system                coredns-5c554d9f6f-fnwqq                                           100m (2%)     200m (5%)   15Mi (0%)        80Mi (0%)
  kube-system                kube-proxy-bfhjr                                                   50m (1%)      100m (2%)   64Mi (0%)        256Mi (1%)
  kube-system                metrics-server-7f4cbf557d-985sj                                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                node-exporter-frdrd                                                10m (0%)      20m (0%)    10Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)
  kube-system                vpn-shoot-7bcd5f4bb-88sc7                                          100m (2%)     300m (7%)   128Mi (0%)       512Mi (3%)
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:54 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:54 -0400   RouteCreated                 RouteController created a route
  OutOfDisk            False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:45 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:42 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure       False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:45 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:42 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:45 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:42 -0400   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:45 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:30:42 -0400   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:48:45 -0400   Thu, 01 Nov 2018 21:31:02 -0400   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
```

As all the results show, my nodes are all healthy and have ample resources with 4CPUs each and 16GB memory each.

Now when I try to deploy my second statefulSet in my namespaces, the Pod remains in `Pending` state. The describe shows the below message:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                From                Message
  ----     ------             ----               ----                -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling   2m (x123 over 7m)  default-scheduler   pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  12s (x26 over 6m)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)
```

I also drained 2 of the nodes, labeled the two nodes and attached a `nodeSelector` to my statefulset to only deploy on those 2 almost empty nodes but the result is the same.

I'm not sure why my pod is trying to `scale-up`. That's not the intention. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
kubectl get po -n jenkins-test -o wide
NAME                                      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE                                             NOMINATED NODE
jenkins-agent         0/1       Pending   0          12m       <none>       <none>                                           <none>
jenkins-master        1/1       Running   0          22m       100.96.1.2   shoot--t--csp-worker-hqh6g-z1-6df8f7dc66-bcj6t   <none>
```

Comment: How did you deploy Jenkins? do you have a pointer to how you deployed it?

Comment: I am setting up a Jenkins master from a custom base image as well as the slave. I am then dynamically attaching the slave to the master using RESTful API calls to the master during the InitContainer stage of the agent. The indication given by Kun is correct. My PVC for the agent had the wrong StroageClass defined in GCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims` , I think it's the key to this problem. About scale up, Pod is created through 'scale from 0 to any instance you defined'.

Comment: Correct. The StorageClass name for the Agent PVC was wrong. I corrected that and it worked. Thanks